# Path reference for added items c#

Tags: c#

I have create new textfile in Visual Studio, by adding item in Solution Explorer. Next step is StreamWriter and save data to textfile. However, no data is saved at all. The StreamWriter only save its data to textfile if referencing to full path.

```
using (StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter("Textfile.txt", true))
```

What is going on and how can I StreamWrite textfile using Visual Studio added item file name?

Solution Explorer after added item:

```
Project
 Properties
 References
 App.config
 Textfile.txt
Program.cs
```

I am able to make a StreamReader and read from the file, but not write to it.

Comment: Add Program.cs into Project, instead of by itself? outside of the Project?

Comment: How do I manage that? I believe Program.cs is inside the Project, but under it. When I drag the item into Program.cs it says "Cannot move 'Textfile.txt'. The destination folder is the same as the source folder.

Comment: Did you check the Debug folder, i.e. the folder where your program is running from?

Comment: There is no textfile that is named textfile in Debug folder.

Comment: Program.cs is outside the project, drag it  right under Project.

Comment: If you want the file to be copied to output folder, right click on Textfile.txt, click Properties and set Build Action as Content. Then StreamWriter should pick up this file correctly.

Comment: Okay so it's under the Project, but why is not StreamWriter working?
 using (StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter("LogFile.txt", true))
        { sw.Write("word");}

Comment: I can read from the textfile but not write to it??

Comment: Can you explain the problem that you are trying to solve in terms of requirements or goals? Usually, programs that you write will never write to files that are in a solution. Files in a solution are artifacts that become your program, and then at runtime your program creates other files. So I think you first need to get those concepts straight, figure out what you really want to accomplish. And then work on the file writing problem, if still necessary.

Comment: I am trying to save data to the textfile in my Project (Solution Explorer). 
If it's not writing to files, where can I find the actual data then when I have to read it to my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-You should not put the text file in your projects. You can check out this sample from MSDN:[Write to a Text File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

- Here is a sample:

  ```
    var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "@\Textfile.txt";
  /// Put your "Textfile.txt" in the same directory with your  [AppName].exe. 
  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
  {
          //Write your code here
  }
  ```

Comment: Is the project able for all other users who I send it to then?  

Why can't I just do like Bob and referee to ("Textfilee.txt")?